# What does it mean when a set is said to be a "finitely generated vector space"?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, terminology, definition

I've somehow managed to go through 3 years of my Maths degree without truly understanding what the term "finitely generated vector space" means.

Generated by what? Generating what? And for what? I have a very vague idea of what this term means and usually gloss over it when doing proofs but I think I just want a simple break-down of the meaning of this.

Answer (score 5):

It means that the vector space has a finite generating set - that is, that a vector space $V$ has got a finite subset $\mathcal{B}$ such that $V = \text{span}\{b \in \mathcal{B}\}$. If the vector space is over a field, then this is equivalent to having a finite basis.

Comment: "If the vector space is over a field", as opposed to what?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I've seen modules over division rings called vector spaces as well.

Comment: I've never seen that. I've heard modules explained as vector spaces over rings, but only in a purely informal sense.